# Mysql fails to Join date records, that is visible in the where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT SUM(`georder`)                                           AS `order`, 
       SUM(quantity)                                            AS quantity, 
       SUM(onhandqty)                                           AS onhandqty, 
       SUM(carryover)                                           AS carryover, 
       SUM(knownloss)                                           AS knownloss, 
       SUM(selloff1)                                            AS selloff1, 
       weekno, 
       YEAR(ardate8n)                                           AS `year`, 
       Concat(GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT IF(flag1<>'N', flag1, '') ORDER BY IF(flag1 
              <>'N', 
              flag1, 
              '') ASC 
              SEPARATOR ''), IF(flag1<>'N' 
                                AND b.id IS NOT NULL, 'N', '')) AS flag1, 
       Date_format(Str_to_date(Concat(Yearweek(ardate8n) + 1, ' Sunday'), 
                   '%X%V %W'), 
       '%c-%e')                                                 AS endoftheweek, 
       b.id 
FROM   sales s 
       /* 
         section starts here
      */
      LEFT JOIN blog b 
         ON s.custno = b.custno 
            AND s.prodno = b.prodno 
            AND ( DATE(s.ardate8n)>=DATE(b.start_date) 
                  AND DATE(s.ardate8n)<=DATE(b.end_date) ) 
       /* 
        section ends here
      */
       JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT `prodno` 
             FROM   `familycode` 
             WHERE  slsfamlycd = 101) f 
         ON f.prodno = s.prodno 
WHERE  s.custno = 25609 
       AND s.deptno = 0 
       AND ( DATE(ardate8n) BETWEEN '2010-11-28' AND '2011-02-26' ) 
GROUP  BY Yearweek(ardate8n) 
ORDER  BY ardate8n DESC;
```

This query outputs

```
45, 0, 146, 217, 0, 75, 09, 2011, 'N', '2-27', 46090
352, 406, 902, 551, 0, 333, 07, 2011, '', '2-20', 
352, 364, 920, 642, 0, 302, 06, 2011, '', '2-13', 
550, 477, 1830, 1465, 0, 688, 06, 2011, '', '2-6', 
968, 846, 1590, 803, 0, 540, 05, 2011, '', '1-30', 
368, 332, 1083, 808, 0, 294, 04, 2011, '', '1-23', 
449, 444, 984, 568, 0, 395, 03, 2011, '', '1-16', 
398, 441, 1090, 689, 0, 367, 02, 2011, 'H', '1-9', 
337, 337, 861, 542, 0, 282, 52, 2010, 'H', '1-2', 
254, 245, 1097, 875, 0, 325, 52, 2010, 'BH', '12-26', 
394, 398, 1024, 677, 0, 316, 51, 2010, 'B', '12-19', 
370, 395, 1066, 699, 0, 364, 50, 2010, '', '12-12', 
399, 386, 882, 528, 0, 353, 49, 2010, 'H', '12-5',
```

As you see there is a 'N' record in the first row.

But the corect output would be to display for the first two rows. For the weekending `2-27` and `2-20`. Why doesn't read out?

If I move the date clause to the where clause I get the proper values in the above table. SQL Query used is linked here: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/348085/

And this outputs the correct two rows:

```
37, 0, 86, 116, 0, 56, 08, 2011, 'N', '2-27', 46089
226, 275, 501, 239, 0, 194, 08, 2011, 'N', '2-20', 46090
```

Table schema is given here: http://paste.pocoo.org/show/348174/

**What is presented here:**

1. a Query with LEFT JOIN, that reads 1 row with 'N' flag (correct would be 2 rows)
2. the same Query with INNER JOIN + While, that reads 2 rows with 'N' flag (correct query, but it uses INNER JOIN)

I don't understand why INNER JOIN + Where condition, doesn't show up in the LEFT JOIN if they are the same logic.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your first query you are using `LEFT JOIN` which does not filter `sales` for the dates, rather outputting `NULL` values for the records that have not match in `b`.

As you can see in you output, `b.id` is `NULL` for every record except the first (which seems to have a match in `b`).

In your second query you move your join condition

```
( DATE(s.ardate8n)>=DATE(b.start_date) 
  AND DATE(s.ardate8n)<=DATE(b.end_date) )
```

into the `WHERE` clause.

This turns the `LEFT JOIN` into an implicit `INNER JOIN`, and the records which don't match are filtered out.

Comment: The problem is: I want to display 'N' = note, when there is at least one relevant note from the blog table. Your assumptions are correct. I would expect that two rows to have the 'N' flag as it comes out with INNER JOIN. So the problem: I need the same two rows also for LEFT JOIN. Why they do not show up?

Comment: @Pentium10: your query is grouping and you are using ungrouped and unaggregated fields (`flag1` and `b.id`) in your `SELECT` clause.

Comment: Thanks for noticing this. I now have to figure out how to resolve this.